# Exportar resultado da consulta como scripts insert

Tags: sql-server

Eu gostaria de exportar o resultado de uma consulta no SQL Server como um script de insert para inserir os dados em outro banco.

Sei que existe a opção de exportar toda a tabela pelo menu "Tarefas -> Gerar Scripts" mas não quero exportar toda a tabela, preciso de apenas alguns registros para fazer testes em outro banco.

ps: Os bancos não estão no mesmo servidor.

Comment: Para bases de dados em servidores diferentes é possível o uso de linked servers (servidores vinculados).

Comment: @JoséDiz Obrigado pela atenção, mas o servidor que me refiro é de desenvolvimento, ele está em uma rede isolada.

Comment: Acrescentei o script generate_inserts na resposta que postei.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente quando eu preciso de algo assim eu faço um `SELECT` que me gere o script de `INSERT` na mão, segue um exemplo de como normalmente eu faço.

Considerando `C1` *INT* e `C2` e `C3` *STRING*.

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO TB1 (C1, C2, C3) VALUES (' + CAST(C1 AS VARCHAR) + ',''' + C2 + ''',''' + C3 + ''')'
FROM TB2
```

Observação no SQLServer duas aspas, '', é transformado em aspas '

Quando você executar esse select ele ira gerar varias linhas de `INSERT`, no qual você só vai precisar executar no seu outro DB

Comment: Praticamente o que eu usei na `procedure` pra gerar os `inserts`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a `procedure` abaixo:

```
if object_id('ferramenta.gerar_insercao', 'P') is null
begin
  exec('create procedure ferramenta.gerar_insercao as');
end;
go

alter procedure ferramenta.gerar_insercao(@schema    varchar(200) = 'dbo',
                                          @tabela    varchar(200),
                                          @where     varchar(max) = null,
                                          @top       int = null,
                                          @insert    varchar(max) output)
as
begin
  declare @insert_campos varchar(max),
          @select        varchar(max),
          @erro          varchar(500),
          @query         varchar(max);

  declare @valores table(descricao varchar(max));

  set nocount on;

  -- Pega a relação de colunas
  select @insert_campos = isnull(@insert_campos + ', ', '') + c.name,
         @select = case type_name(c.system_type_id)
                      when 'varchar' then isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + ' isnull('''''''' + cast(' + c.name + ' as varchar) + '''''''', ''null'')'
                      when 'datetime' then isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + ' isnull('''''''' + convert(varchar, ' + c.name + ', 121) + '''''''', ''null'')'
                      else isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + 'isnull(cast(' + c.name + ' as varchar), ''null'')'
                    end
    from sys.columns c with(nolock)
         inner join sys.tables t with(nolock) on t.object_id = c.object_id
         inner join sys.schemas s with(nolock) on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
   where s.name = @schema
     and t.name = @tabela;

  -- Caso não tenha encontrado as colunas...
  if @insert_campos is null or @select is null
  begin
    set @erro = 'Tabela ' + @schema + '.' + @tabela + ' não existe na base de dados.';
    raiserror(@erro, 16, 1);
    return;
  end;

  set @insert_campos = 'insert into ' + @schema + '.' + @tabela + '(' + @insert_campos + ')';

  if isnull(@where, '') <> '' and charindex('where', ltrim(rtrim(@where))) < 1
  begin
    set @where = 'where ' + @where;
  end
  else
  begin
    set @where = '';
  end;

  set @query = 'select ' + isnull('top(' + cast(@top as varchar) + ')', '') + @select + ' from ' + @schema + '.' + @tabela + ' with (nolock) ' + @where;

  insert into @valores(descricao)
  exec(@query);

  set @insert = isnull(@insert + char(10), '') + '--' + upper(@schema + '.' + @tabela);

  select @insert = @insert + char(10) + @insert_campos + char(10) + 'values(' + v.descricao + ');' + char(10) + 'go' + char(10)
    from @valores v
   where isnull(v.descricao, '') <> '';
end;
go
```

Da seguinte forma:

```
declare @insert varchar(max),
        @parte  varchar(max),
        @inicio int,
        @final  int;

set @inicio = 1;

exec ferramenta.gerar_insercao @schema = 'dbo',
                               @tabela = 'cliente',
                               @where  = 'codigo = 1',
                               @insert = @insert output;

-- Dá um comando "print" a cada quebra de linha para não estourar o tamanho máximo de 8000
while len(@insert) > 0
begin
  set @final = charindex(char(10), @insert);

  if @final = 0
  begin
    set @final = len(@insert) + 1;
  end;

  print substring(@insert, @inicio, @final - 1);
  set @insert = substring(@insert, @final + 1, len(@insert) - @final + 1);
end;
```

O resultado seria algo assim:

```
--DBO.CLIENTE
insert into dbo.cliente(codigo, nome, tipo)
values(1, 'NOME DO CLIENTE', 'F');
go
```

Caso não queria utilizar o `where`, você pode usar o parâmetro `@top`:

```
declare @insert varchar(max),
        @parte  varchar(max),
        @inicio int,
        @final  int;

set @inicio = 1;

exec ferramenta.gerar_insercao @schema = 'dbo',
                               @tabela = 'cliente',
                               @top    = 100,
                               @insert = @insert output;

-- Dá um comando "print" a cada quebra de linha para não estourar o tamanho máximo de 8000
while len(@insert) > 0
begin
  set @final = charindex(char(10), @insert);

  if @final = 0
  begin
    set @final = len(@insert) + 1;
  end;

  print substring(@insert, @inicio, @final - 1);
  set @insert = substring(@insert, @final + 1, len(@insert) - @final + 1);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode exportar/importar diretamente entre os bancos de dados, sem necessidade de arquivos intermediários, e delimitando na cláusula WHERE as restrições para obter "*apenas alguns registros*".
Basta ter permissão de acesso aos dois bancos de dados.

Se os dois bancos de dados estão na mesma instância:

```
-- código #1 v3
USE outrobanco;

INSERT into tabela 
  SELECT ...
    from banco.dbo.tabela
    where ...
```

Mas se os bancos de dados estiverem em instâncias diferentes, primeiro é necessário vincular o banco de dados de origem ao "outro banco". Informações em [Criar servidores vinculados](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff772782.aspx). Após,

```
-- código #2
USE outrobanco;

INSERT into tabela 
  SELECT ...
    from servidor.banco.dbo.tabela
    where ...
```

---

**GENERATE_INSERTS**
Mas, se necessita mesmo de um arquivo intermediário, avalie se o script [generate_inserts](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt) atende ao que necessita. Documentação inclusa no script.

Comment: O `.` funciona dentro do `[]` também?

Comment: @Sorack: No código #1, o par [ ] define algo opcional, conforme a notação utilizada na documentação do SQL Server.  // O código #1 é um esboço; inclusive constam ... nas cláusulas SELECT e WHERE.

Comment: Beleza José, era só uma dúvida que eu tinha mesmo, obrigado

Comment: @Sorack: Modifiquei a resposta, após sua observação. Quanto mais detalhado, melhor.